# How to solve Parameter Sniffing problem in a query with 'in' operator

Tags: azure-sql-database, parameter-sniffing

I have a parameter sniffing problem in this `Azure SQL Server` query with `in` operator:

```
    Select Col1, Col2, ..., Coln from T1 Join T2 
    On T1.Id = T2.T1Id
    Where T2.Col2 in ('uniqueIdentifier_1','uniqueIdentifier_2',..., 'uniqueIdentifier_m')
```

I have around 30-40 unique-identifiers in where clause. And I can not replace them because they are primary keys from another table in another `Azure SQL Database`. As you can see there is a range of different unique-identifiers and it is difficult to tune it.
Would you please guide me to solve a parameter sniff problem?

Comment: Create a temporary table where you insert one unique identifier per row and then use a join instead of IN

Comment: Unfortunately, I tired and almost the same execution plans

Comment: Did you index your temp table?

Comment: You may also consider revealing the plan as well as ddl for the tables involved